# jQuery mobile: Slider Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a slider calculator with Jquery UI and then noticed it doesnt work on touch devices, so I start over with Jquery Mobile.

For some reason I can update the value of the slider with the buttons, but the slider itself won't move.

```
$("#plus1").on("mousedown", function () {
    $('#slider-vertical').val(Number($('#slider-vertical').val())+25)
});
```

Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/MJ5WT/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#plus1").on("mousedown", function () {
    $('#slider-vertical').val(Number($('#slider-vertical').val())+25);
    $('#slider-vertical').slider('refresh');
});
```

You did not have Mobile activated on the jsFiddle and you need to use the `refresh` option to visually refresh it.

[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/MJ5WT/1/)

Comment: Yea thanks. The mobile was in the external resources though. The refresh was what I was looking for ...

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the answer myself:

I needed to add *.slider("refresh")* to it:

```
$("#plus1").on("mousedown", function(){
$('#slider-vertical').val(Number($('#slider-vertical').val())+25).slider("refresh");
});
```